# Test exceptions in private delegate method

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, exception, mvvm

I'm designing a WPF application in MVVM manner and I have an issue how to test that exception was thrown when message was sent by another viewmodel. I'm using nUnit for unit testing.

I try to test that delegate throws an exception when object sent via messenger is null.

Please find simple code below

**CTOR** (all dependencies are injected using Autofac)

```cs
    public ManagerViewModel (IMessenger messenger)
    {
       messenger.Register<Person> (this, OnPersonSent)
    }
```

**Delegate**

```cs
    private void OnPersonSent()
    {
       if(Person is null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
```

**Unit test**

When I try to assert as below it doesn't catch the exceptions. The situation is that when messenger sends message the OnPersonSent method should throws an exception - but how to catch it using Assert.Throws if this assertion catches only the exception throws by a method passed in lambda expression (if I'm wrong please correct me). Test case below:

```cs
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
      messenger = new Messenger() // MVVMLight messenger
      sut = new ManagerViewModel(messenger)
    }
```

Below in lambda expression I'm sending null object in order to throw an exception by a delegate which is pointed above

```cs
    [Test] 
    public void OnPersonSent_WhenNull_ThrowsException()
    {    
           Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(()=>messenger.Send((Person)null));
    }
```

Thank you very much for your help.

PS. Of course this case is simplified in order to clearly show the issue

Comment: Include the complete test, the subject under test, and any dependencies used.

Comment: The simplification of the case makes it more difficult to understand the actual problem and we are left to guess what the true problem is.

Comment: I tried to clarify a bit more in the post. Key question is - how to assert that delegate method throws the exception. It is not a problem to verify that if in lambda expresision of assert statement the method throwing exception is passed. But how to do it with delegate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review the following minimal example to see how one can test the invocation of the delegate for expected behavior

Note: *(using MOQ mocking framework to mock dependencies.)*

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass {
    [TestMethod]
    public void OnPersonSent_WhenNull_ThrowsException() {
        //Arrange
        var mock = new Mock<IMessenger>();
        Action<Person> callback = null;
        //setup the mock so the delegate can be captured when registered
        mock
            .Setup(_ => _.Register(It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<Action<Person>>(), It.IsAny<bool>()))
            .Callback((object obj, Action<Person> action, bool _) => {
                callback = action; //<--
            });

        //Act
        //create view model to invoke register and capture callback in mock
        var sut = new ManagerViewModel(mock.Object);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(callback);
        Assert.ThrowsException<ArgumentNullException>(() => callback(null));
    }
}

public class ManagerViewModel {
    public ManagerViewModel(IMessenger messenger) {
        messenger.Register<Person>(this, OnPersonSent);
    }

    private void OnPersonSent(Person person) {
        if (person is null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
}

internal class Person {
}
```

A mock of the messenger was created and setup to expect the appropriate `Register` member to be invoked. The mock is setup to capture the delegate method provided in the subject class's constructor.

Once the delegate has been captured, it can be invoked and the expected behavior asserted.

Invoking the delegate in the test is the same as when the actual messenger invokes registered delegates when `Send` is invoked.

The shown approach above isolates the invocation in a unit test.

Note the above test uses the default MSTest, but it can be easily applied to other test frameworks.

Comment: Thank you very much Nkosi for pointing me how to properly register mock messenger in order to use delegate. I've just encapsulated this logic (in generic way) in my TestBaseClass and reuse it in my tests.